# Why is my table row 0.4px wider than I set it to be?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have looked around a lot, but I can’t figure out what is going on here.

I have a table with two [td](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td)'s in the first row.
The left *td* has a image and should be *h:200px* and *w:200px*.
The right *td* has some text and should be *h:200px* and *w:430px*.
So the total should be *w:630px* and *h:200px*, but somehow if I inspect the *[tr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr)*, its *h:200px* and *w:630.4px*, so 0.4 too many which I can’t figure out where it’s from.
I have the margin and padding set to 0 pixels.

```css
#logo {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#headerText {
    height: 200px;
    width: 430px;
    background-color: #660066;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Picture with Inspector: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLZa8.jpg

Comment: Could you show us the result pls?

Comment: @GogoDev added a picture to the post.

Comment: The picture link appears to be broken.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to add both your HTML and CSS codes so that we can see the result and inspect it. But from your explanation, I would say there are two things to consider:

1. If you want to control the size of a cell, you need to wrap the content in a div or other block elements.
2. Try adding `overflow: hidden;` and `white-space: nowrap;`to your table cell. Use either one that works for you.